# Wrangler plugin not working (Known bug with the 2.83 build)

Tags: node-editor

I'm getting this error now everytime i try to load the textures with the shortcut control shift t...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is not working on 2.8.3 ?

[image]

Comment: It’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to get the Wrangler

Comment: it looks like some file is in a different drive D: and not C:

Answer (score 5):

Most likely issue is that you don't have node wrangler enabled.

How to enable it is by going to

Preferences

Then to addons
[image]

Then search for node wrangler and press the check box beside it.
[image]

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for that answer. However i'm getting some script problem when i try to do this.... I putted on the post.

Comment: Try reinstalling blender with a .zip

Comment: Found the problem. Wranger does not import textures from another drive. Like im using my hdd to store textures and whatnot because my ssd is just 240gb.

Comment: So report as a bug ?

Comment: Yeah that is the best option

Comment: Alright. Thanks again man.